# How to log transaction events in grails

Tags: grails, logging, transactions

We have `@grails.transaction.Transactional` annotation in grails. What is the best way to log when transaction started and finished? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just add to your logging config the line

```
trace   'org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor'
```